# Karma/Jasmine: TypeError: $scope.loadCss is not a function!

Tags: angularjs, юнит-тесты, jasmine, karma

**Это мой app.js файл.**

```
var famboxWebApp = angular.module('famboxWebApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'pascalprecht.translate', // angular-translate
    'tmh.dynamicLocale',// angular-dynamic-locale
    'ui.bootstrap'
])
        .constant('LOCALES', {
            'locales': {
                'hy_AM': 'Armenia',
                'ru_RU': 'Russian',
                'en_US': 'English'
            },
            'preferredLocale': 'en_US'
        })
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider
                    .when('/:language', {
                        templateUrl:'views/main.html',
                        controller: 'MainCtrl',
                        controllerAs: 'main'
                    })
         ----------------
        })
```

**Это main.js фаил.**

```
angular.module('famboxWebApp')
            .controller('MainCtrl', function ($http, $scope, $routeParams,$rootScope) {

                $scope.commonUrl = COMMON_URL;
                $rootScope.$watch('CURRENT_LANGUAGE', function() { 
                $scope.currentLang = $rootScope.CURRENT_LANGUAGE;
                });

                $scope.homePageFirstSlider = function () {              
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: COMMON_URL + CURRENT_LANGUAGE + '/api/getslideritems/main'
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        $scope.Data = response.data;
                        $scope.loadCss('mainCarousel');
                    },
                        function errorCallback(response) {
                           // location.href = "404.html";
                        });
                };
    $scope.homePageFirstSlider();
    });
```

**Это тест на Karma/Jasmine**

```
describe('test Angular JS project', function() {
beforeEach(module('famboxWebApp'));
beforeEach(module('ngAnimate'));
beforeEach(module('ngCookies'));
beforeEach(module('ngResource'));
beforeEach(module('ngRoute'));
beforeEach(module('ngSanitize'));
beforeEach(module('ngTouch'));
beforeEach(module('pascalprecht.translate'));
beforeEach(module('tmh.dynamicLocale'));
beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));
    var scope;
    var controller;
        var httpBackend;

beforeEach(module(function ( $translateProvider) {            
        $translateProvider.useLoader();  
    }));

beforeEach(inject(function ( $rootScope, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {

scope = $rootScope.$new();
httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {   
$scope:scope
//$routeParams: {}
});
}));

 it("test getslideritems", inject(function ($httpBackend) {     
 var jsonlist = [{"id":"1","link":"..\/Smart#Smart","uri":"pesacun-krkesic","time":null,"year":"2011","image":"slide1.png","videoName":"The Fianc\u00e9 from Circus","genre":["Comedy"],"country":["Armenia"],"countryImage":["AM.png"]},{"id":"52","link":"vana-tsovun-arshaluysy","uri":"vana-tsovun-arshaluysy","time":"93 min.","year":"2011","image":"slide5.png","videoName":"Sunrise over Lake Van","genre":["Melodrama"],"country":["Armenia"],"countryImage":["AM.png"]},{"id":"61","link":"yerankyuni","uri":"yerankyuni","time":"84 min.","year":"1967","image":"yerankyuni.png","videoName":"\u0422riangle","genre":["Historic "],"country":["Armenia"],"countryImage":["AM.png"]},{"id":"58","link":"arajin-siro-ergy","uri":"arajin-siro-ergy","time":"109 min.","year":"1958","image":"arajin-siro-ergy.png","videoName":"The song of the first love","genre":["Melodrama"],"country":["Armenia"],"countryImage":["AM.png"]}];
 $httpBackend.whenGET('views/main.html').respond();
 $httpBackend.whenGET(COMMON_URL + CURRENT_LANGUAGE + '/api/getslideritems/main').respond(200, jsonlist);
 $httpBackend.expectGET('/eng/api/getslideritems/main');


 var json = [[{"id":"81","videoType":"musics","videoTypeName":"musics","rating":"{\"kinopoisk_rating\":\"0\",\"imdb_rating\":\"0\"}","fambox_rating":"0","uri":"tigran-petrosyan-um","year":"2012","content":"Music: Hayko, lyrics by: Vardan Zadoyan, producer: Artyom Hakobyan, Mihran Stepanyan, information sponsor : \"Day TV\"","videoName":"Tigran Petrosyan \"Whom\"","price":"0","serialId":"0","watchList":false,"seasonId":"0","serial_number":"0","genre":["HIP-HOP"],"countryName":["Armenia"],"video_main":["Tigran_Petrosyan_um.png"],"country_image":["AM.png"]},{"id":"82","videoType":"musics","videoTypeName":"musics","rating":"{\"kinopoisk_rating\":\"0\",\"imdb_rating\":\"0\"}","fambox_rating":"0","uri":"tigran-petrosyan-kgam","year":"2012","content":"Music: Hayko, lyrics by: Vardan Zadoyan, producer: Nur, information sponsor : \"Day TV\".","videoName":"Tigran Petrosyan \"I will come\"","price":"0","serialId":"0","watchList":false,"seasonId":"0","serial_number":"0","genre":["HIP-HOP"],"countryName":["Armenia"],"video_main":["Tigran_Petrosyan_kgam.png"],"country_image":["AM.png"]}],2];
 $httpBackend.whenGET(COMMON_URL + CURRENT_LANGUAGE + '/api/home/musics/main/0/8').respond(200, json);
 $httpBackend.expectGET('/eng/api/home/musics/main/0/8');
 $httpBackend.flush();
 scope.name; 
 scope.homePageFirstSlider();

 expect(scope.Data).not.toEqual([]);
 console.log(scope.Data); 
 console.log(scope.DataTvMusic);
    })); 
});
```

Ошибка:

> TypeError: $scope.loadCss is not a function
>         at successCallback (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/scripts/controllers/main.js:28:28)
>         at processQueue (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15552:28)
>         at /var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15568:27
>         at Scope.$eval (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16820:28)
>         at Scope.$digest (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16636:31)
>         at Scope.$apply (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16928:24)
>         at done (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11266:47)
>         at handleResponse (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1352:9)
>         at Function.$httpBackend.flush (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1788:26)
>         at Object. (tests/getslideritems-main.js:110:15)     Error: Declaration Location
>         at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/var/www/html/famboxv2/public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2778:25)
>         at Suite. (tests/getslideritems-main.js:100:28)
>         at tests/getslideritems-main.js:71:1 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs) PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)

Когда в mian.js  закрыто следующая строка - ***$scope.loadCss('mainCarousel');***, то у меня все работает, я получаю json и могу сравнивать. В чем проблема?

**karma.conf.js файл**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [


      '../../public/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_aa.js' ,
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',      
      '../../public/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-dynamic-locale/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js',     
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js' , 
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-translate-handler-log/angular-translate-handler-log.js' ,
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-touch.js' ,
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js' ,
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.js' ,
      '../../public/bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.min.js' ,

      '/node_modules/angular-translate-loader-pluggable/dist/angular-translate-loader-pluggable.js',
      '/node_modules/angular-translate-loader-pluggable/dist/angular-translate-loader-pluggable.min.js',
      '/node_modules/angular-translate-loader-pluggable/dist/angular-translate-loader-pluggable.min.js.map',

      '../../public/scripts/app.js', 
      '../../public/scripts/controllers/main.js',

      'tests/getslideritems-main.js'

  ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
         ],



    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {

    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду, ваш $scope понятия не имеет что такое loadCss(). Вы возможно забыли или подключить какой-то сервис/модуль или же функция вообще не взаимодействует с $scope внутри данного контроллера. К сожалению, больше подсказать не могу т.к. неясно что это за функция и где она объявлена у вас.

Comment: **$scope понятия не имеет что такое loadCss()** , Вы имете введу в файле main.js??  Если поможет я добавила karma.conf.js file.

Comment: лучше всего воспользуйтесь поиском по вашему коду и найдите , есть ли у вас вообще данный метод loadCss() ? И добавьте его код и объявление к вопросу. К сожалению conf.js не помог =(

Comment: Вы помогли спасибоооо большое. Я нашла loadCss() функцию добавила  в тест ,  и  $scope уже видит  loadCss(). )))))

Comment: Рад помочь=) Получается, просто не был подключен модуль с данной фнукцией?

Comment: Ну да получается так )))))

Comment: Ну ничего страшного, так всегда бывает что главная боль при работе с кодом кроется в мелочах. Главное - задача решена и все довольны=)

Comment: Да это всегда так. Проблема всегда бывает в мелочах. Спасибо еще раз, и извините за полохой русский ))